# Angular UI router error Could not resolve 'child.state' from 'parent'

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm having the above error in angular ui router when trying to load a state. I'm trying to have vertical tabs which, when clicked, give details right next to the tabs. I'm using resolve to get the details by id from my service.
Below is my routing config

```
        .state('franchise', {
            url: "/franchise",
            controller: "FranchiseCtrl",
            templateUrl: "tpl/franchise.html"
        })
        .state('franchise.detail', {
            params: {
                franchiseId : "defaultId", 
                franchiseName: "defaultName"
            },
            url: "/:franchiseName",
            controller: function($scope, fran) {
                $scope.franchiseDetail = fran;
            },
            templateUrl: "partials/franchise-detail.html",
            resolve: {
                fran:  function($http, $stateParams) {
                    var url = "path/to/my/service" + $stateParams.franchiseId;
                    return $http.get(url)
                        .then(function(res){ return res.data; });
                }
            }
        })
```

This is my parent's template

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="franchise in franchises">
      <a ui-sref="frachise.detail({ franchiseId: franchise.id,
                                    franchiseName: franchise.name })">
         Franchise {{ franchise.name }}
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I already tried putting my resolve in the parent but it kept giving the same error.

Comment: what are the error in console?

Comment: Error: Could not resolve 'frachise.detail' from state 'franchise'

Comment: Use  parent: 'franchise' in  this  .state('franchise.detail', {
            params: { parent: 'franchise' .................

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in the word `franchise` (you missed the 'n'), should be:

```
<a ui-sref="franchise.detail({ franchiseId: franchise.id, franchiseName: franchise.name })">
      Franchise {{ franchise.name }}
</a>
```